# How to Set TableColumnValue JavaFX Table View

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, javafx, javafx-8

Hello everyone I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<courses>
    <course>
        <name>Java</name>
        <instructor>
            <name>Bohdana Dumanska</name>
            <acceptance>yes</acceptance>
        </instructor>
        <students>
            <student>
                <name>Brenden Walski</name>
                <acceptance>yes</acceptance>
            </student>
            <student>
                <name>Ty Flint</name>
                <acceptance>yes</acceptance>
            </student>
        </students>
        <time>Monday 6:00 - 8:00</time>
        <availability>yes</availability>
        <studentsEnrolled>2</studentsEnrolled>
        <maxStudents>30</maxStudents>
    </course>
    <course>
        <name>Physics</name>
        <instructor>
            <name>Jack Nelson</name>
            <acceptance>yes</acceptance>
        </instructor>
        <students>
            <student>
                <name>Nazariy Dumic</name>
                <acceptance>yes</acceptance>
            </student>
            <student>
                <name>Bren Awesome</name>
                <acceptance>yes</acceptance>
            </student>
        </students>
        <time>Tuesday 6:00 - 8:00</time>
        <availability>yes</availability>
        <studentsEnrolled>2</studentsEnrolled>
        <maxStudents>30</maxStudents>
    </course>
</courses>
```

With that NetBeans created these classes from the xsd file:

```
package schedule.app.courses;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="course" maxOccurs="unbounded">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;sequence>
 *                   &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *                   &lt;element name="instructor">
 *                     &lt;complexType>
 *                       &lt;complexContent>
 *                         &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                           &lt;sequence>
 *                             &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *                             &lt;element name="acceptance" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *                           &lt;/sequence>
 *                         &lt;/restriction>
 *                       &lt;/complexContent>
 *                     &lt;/complexType>
 *                   &lt;/element>
 *                   &lt;element name="students">
 *                     &lt;complexType>
 *                       &lt;complexContent>
 *                         &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                           &lt;sequence>
 *                             &lt;element name="student" maxOccurs="unbounded">
 *                               &lt;complexType>
 *                                 &lt;complexContent>
 *                                   &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                                     &lt;sequence>
 *                                       &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *                                       &lt;element name="acceptance" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *                                     &lt;/sequence>
 *                                   &lt;/restriction>
 *                                 &lt;/complexContent>
 *                               &lt;/complexType>
 *                             &lt;/element>
 *                           &lt;/sequence>
 *                         &lt;/restriction>
 *                       &lt;/complexContent>
 *                     &lt;/complexType>
 *                   &lt;/element>
 *                   &lt;element name="time" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *                   &lt;element name="availability" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *                   &lt;element name="studentsEnrolled" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/>
 *                   &lt;element name="maxStudents" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/>
 *                 &lt;/sequence>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "course"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "courses")
public class Courses {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<Courses.Course> course;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the course property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the course property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getCourse().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link Courses.Course }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Courses.Course> getCourse() {
        if (course == null) {
            course = new ArrayList<Courses.Course>();
        }
        return this.course;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
     *         &lt;element name="instructor">
     *           &lt;complexType>
     *             &lt;complexContent>
     *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *                 &lt;sequence>
     *                   &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
     *                   &lt;element name="acceptance" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
     *                 &lt;/sequence>
     *               &lt;/restriction>
     *             &lt;/complexContent>
     *           &lt;/complexType>
     *         &lt;/element>
     *         &lt;element name="students">
     *           &lt;complexType>
     *             &lt;complexContent>
     *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *                 &lt;sequence>
     *                   &lt;element name="student" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     *                     &lt;complexType>
     *                       &lt;complexContent>
     *                         &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *                           &lt;sequence>
     *                             &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
     *                             &lt;element name="acceptance" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
     *                           &lt;/sequence>
     *                         &lt;/restriction>
     *                       &lt;/complexContent>
     *                     &lt;/complexType>
     *                   &lt;/element>
     *                 &lt;/sequence>
     *               &lt;/restriction>
     *             &lt;/complexContent>
     *           &lt;/complexType>
     *         &lt;/element>
     *         &lt;element name="time" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
     *         &lt;element name="availability" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
     *         &lt;element name="studentsEnrolled" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/>
     *         &lt;element name="maxStudents" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "name",
        "instructor",
        "students",
        "time",
        "availability",
        "studentsEnrolled",
        "maxStudents"
    })
    public static class Course {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected String name;
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected Courses.Course.Instructor instructor;
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected Courses.Course.Students students;
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected String time;
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected String availability;
        protected int studentsEnrolled;
        protected int maxStudents;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the name property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the name property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setName(String value) {
            this.name = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the instructor property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link Courses.Course.Instructor }
         *     
         */
        public Courses.Course.Instructor getInstructor() {
            return instructor;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the instructor property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link Courses.Course.Instructor }
         *     
         */
        public void setInstructor(Courses.Course.Instructor value) {
            this.instructor = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the students property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link Courses.Course.Students }
         *     
         */
        public Courses.Course.Students getStudents() {
            return students;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the students property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link Courses.Course.Students }
         *     
         */
        public void setStudents(Courses.Course.Students value) {
            this.students = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the time property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the time property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setTime(String value) {
            this.time = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the availability property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getAvailability() {
            return availability;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the availability property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setAvailability(String value) {
            this.availability = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the studentsEnrolled property.
         * 
         */
        public int getStudentsEnrolled() {
            return studentsEnrolled;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the studentsEnrolled property.
         * 
         */
        public void setStudentsEnrolled(int value) {
            this.studentsEnrolled = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the maxStudents property.
         * 
         */
        public int getMaxStudents() {
            return maxStudents;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the maxStudents property.
         * 
         */
        public void setMaxStudents(int value) {
            this.maxStudents = value;
        }


        /**
         * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
         * 
         * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
         * 
         * <pre>
         * &lt;complexType>
         *   &lt;complexContent>
         *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
         *       &lt;sequence>
         *         &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
         *         &lt;element name="acceptance" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
         *       &lt;/sequence>
         *     &lt;/restriction>
         *   &lt;/complexContent>
         * &lt;/complexType>
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         */
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "name",
            "acceptance"
        })
        public static class Instructor {

            @XmlElement(required = true)
            protected String name;
            @XmlElement(required = true)
            protected String acceptance;

            /**
             * Gets the value of the name property.
             * 
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the name property.
             * 
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public void setName(String value) {
                this.name = value;
            }

            /**
             * Gets the value of the acceptance property.
             * 
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public String getAcceptance() {
                return acceptance;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the acceptance property.
             * 
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public void setAcceptance(String value) {
                this.acceptance = value;
            }

        }


        /**
         * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
         * 
         * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
         * 
         * <pre>
         * &lt;complexType>
         *   &lt;complexContent>
         *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
         *       &lt;sequence>
         *         &lt;element name="student" maxOccurs="unbounded">
         *           &lt;complexType>
         *             &lt;complexContent>
         *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
         *                 &lt;sequence>
         *                   &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
         *                   &lt;element name="acceptance" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
         *                 &lt;/sequence>
         *               &lt;/restriction>
         *             &lt;/complexContent>
         *           &lt;/complexType>
         *         &lt;/element>
         *       &lt;/sequence>
         *     &lt;/restriction>
         *   &lt;/complexContent>
         * &lt;/complexType>
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         */
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "student"
        })
        public static class Students {

            @XmlElement(required = true)
            protected List<Courses.Course.Students.Student> student;

            /**
             * Gets the value of the student property.
             * 
             * <p>
             * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
             * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
             * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
             * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the student property.
             * 
             * <p>
             * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
             * <pre>
             *    getStudent().add(newItem);
             * </pre>
             * 
             * 
             * <p>
             * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
             * {@link Courses.Course.Students.Student }
             * 
             * 
             */
            public List<Courses.Course.Students.Student> getStudent() {
                if (student == null) {
                    student = new ArrayList<Courses.Course.Students.Student>();
                }
                return this.student;
            }


            /**
             * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
             * 
             * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
             * 
             * <pre>
             * &lt;complexType>
             *   &lt;complexContent>
             *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
             *       &lt;sequence>
             *         &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
             *         &lt;element name="acceptance" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
             *       &lt;/sequence>
             *     &lt;/restriction>
             *   &lt;/complexContent>
             * &lt;/complexType>
             * </pre>
             * 
             * 
             */
            @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
            @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                "name",
                "acceptance"
            })
            public static class Student {

                @XmlElement(required = true)
                protected String name;
                @XmlElement(required = true)
                protected String acceptance;

                /**
                 * Gets the value of the name property.
                 * 
                 * @return
                 *     possible object is
                 *     {@link String }
                 *     
                 */
                public String getName() {
                    return name;
                }

                /**
                 * Sets the value of the name property.
                 * 
                 * @param value
                 *     allowed object is
                 *     {@link String }
                 *     
                 */
                public void setName(String value) {
                    this.name = value;
                }

                /**
                 * Gets the value of the acceptance property.
                 * 
                 * @return
                 *     possible object is
                 *     {@link String }
                 *     
                 */
                public String getAcceptance() {
                    return acceptance;
                }

                /**
                 * Sets the value of the acceptance property.
                 * 
                 * @param value
                 *     allowed object is
                 *     {@link String }
                 *     
                 */
                public void setAcceptance(String value) {
                    this.acceptance = value;
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

There is also an ObjectFactory but I don't think that I need to include it in here. 
So I am trying to inset e all the values from xml to the table by using this:

```
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            courses = (Courses)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("courses.xml"));
            courseList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(courses.getCourse());
```

Now how would I set the data to a cellvalue factoy. I am trying to use lambadaExpression like this:

```
 TableColumn name = new TableColumn("Name");
 name.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.toString(courseList....???
```

I don't know how I would insert the values into tableColumn.I am sorry for all the comments that are in the classes file. 
Please help. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `TableView<Courses.Course>` and a `TableColumn<Courses.Course, String>` I think you need

```
TableColumn<Courses.Course, Name> name = new TableColumn<>("Name");
name.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getName()));
```

Comment: Thank You So much. That worked! I probably would have never figured that out!

Comment: On more question what would I do for like maxStudents where I would have to assign an integer. I  try to use ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper but it gives me an error saying ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper cannot be converted to ObservableValue<Integer>